# How to drop articles or remove tables without stopping transactional replication on SQL 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I need to remove tables or articles on one of publication, how can I do it without stopping replication which is set up as transactional replication on SQL 2008?

Answer (score 1):

From:  ms-help://MS.SQLCC.v10/MS.SQLSVR.v10.en/s10rp_4deptrbl/html/b148e907-e1f2-483b-bdb2-59ea596efceb.htm

Articles can be dropped from a publication at any time, but you must take into account the following behaviors...

How:  ms-help://MS.SQLCC.v10/MS.SQLSVR.v10.en/s10rp_1devconc/html/185b58fc-38c0-4abe-822e-6ec20066c863.htm